# How to disable printing user data in Ignite log

Tags: security, user-input, ignite

In debug mode, Ignite seems to be printing lot of data especially user data like the key value of cache, data messages exchanged.
In secure environment it is not safe to expose this data in logs. 
I checked this in the ignite code but couldn't find any such setting to disable user data printing in debug mode, also most of the time in debug mode it just prints the class holding the data like the class_name, fields and values in the class and so on.
Does any one know how to disable printing user data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `IGNITE_TO_STRING_INCLUDE_SENSITIVE` environment variable or Java system property to `false`.

Such as

```
% JVM_OPTS=-DIGNITE_TO_STRING_INCLUDE_SENSITIVE=false bin/ignite.sh -v
```

If you find any issues where user data is still printed, please do not hesitate to file a ticket against Apache `IGNITE` Jira.